# What model does use the GenerativeFill site?

Tags: image-generation

It looks like it is more powerful than DALL-E 3! It also allows negative prompts.

I mean this website: https://generativefill.com

Comment: Do you mean Adobe's generative fill in Photoshop? You should give more details - e.g. links - and explain *why* you think it is "more powerful". What does the model do that DALL-E 3 does not do, or in what way are the results better in your opinion?

Comment: @NeilSlater I've added a link. The results are more realistic.

Comment: There is no information available it seems. I would not currently trust this website with your contact details or money. On https://generativefill.io/page/contact-us they give a US headquarters address which does not appear to exist, and their phone numbers are Swedish. It may not be a scam, but something seems off to me

Comment: @NeilSlater yes, and also the tabs "Free AI Canvas", "AI Image Generator" and "Free AI Generator" seem to have the same effect. On the other hand, the quality is very good, like of Midjourney. It is free and seemingly unlimited.

Comment: I'd guess at a (maybe tuned) SDXL model. Another sus thing - the "recent" images in the gallery don't change, and the most recent one is 3 days ago. At best these guys are very new and not ready yet, which means I will double down on this not being some brand new model.

Comment: @NeilSlater is there a way to test, what model it is?

Comment: @NeilSlater it is even better than BlueWillow.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to tell what model it is except via experience with a range of results. In addition the site could add pre- and post- processing, and be using custom tuned or mixed models (SDXL toolkit allows you to merge models and create useful hybrids). I would still suspect SDXL here, because it is freely available, with lots of supporting scripts, so a really small unknown company could set it up provided they could pay the rental for a few GPU servers in the cloud.